# How to render images(files) from S3 bucket blocked all public access in frontend( Private Write, Private read)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have uploaded file to S3 bucket using aws-sdk as:

```
async function uploadFileToAws(file){
    const fileName = `new_file_${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`;
    const mimetype = file.mimetype;
    const params = {
        Bucket: config.awsS3BucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: file.data,
        ContentType: mimetype,
        // ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    const res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(params, (err, data) => err == null ? resolve(data) : reject(err));
    });
    return { secure_url: res.Location };
}
```

If we allow the bucket permission to public read then there is no problem, but we have the requirement of blocking public-read(public-access) and only allow the access of bucket object or image to be visible in owns products only(mobile and web apps) with the help of access Id and secret key or any other similar approach. Is this possible? does aws S3 provide such services?

I have gone through aws s3 documentation, googled, and walked through multiple StackOverflow threads and some blogs but no luck. I would really appreciate the suggestion, tips, help.

Comment: Do your users have to  authenticate to you app or website first before they can access the images?

Comment: Yes we have user authentication before they can access the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could consider two options.

The first one would be through CloudFront and signed urls or cookies as explained in

- [Serving Private Content with Signed URLs and Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Basically, in this approach you would setup a CloudFront distribution which would be used to serve your private images. Since the users are authenticated, your backend would need to verify whether they can access the given image, and if so, generate a signed URL for the file. The signed url would enable the access to the said file. Details of this procedure are described in [How Signed URLs Work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-how-signed-urls-work).

The second possibility would be through [pre-signed S3 URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). It is somehow similar to the first one, except that it does not involve any extra service, such as CloudFront. Again, since users are authenticated, your back-end would verify their rights to view the given image, and generate pre-signed S3 url to enable them a temporary access to the image.

In both cases, bucket's do not need to be public. Access to the images is controlled by your back-end.